# Connected graph has 10 vertices and 1 bridge. How many edges can it have? Give upper and lower bound.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

Need help with the task above. I've solved it but I am not sure if I am right. My solution is:

To determine upper bound let's take complete $K_9$ and add one vertex in such a way we get a bridge. Hence our upper bound is 9*(9-1)/2 (number of edges in complete graph on 9 vertices) + 1 (bridge) = 37.

As for lower bound, let's take the subgraph of $K_9$ such that it contains minimum edges needed to remain connected. Then, applying the same logic as before, simply add one vertex and connect it to the graph. So number of edges will be: 9 (min connected subgraph of $K_9$) + 1 (bridge) = 10.

That sounds quite right to me but I am not sure. I would really appreciate if anyone could comment on my solution.

Comment: You give two constructions with $37$ and $10$ edges, but you didn't argue why those are upper and lower bounds respectively. How do you know that there isn't a complicated graph with more that $37$ edges?

Comment: Connected graph on 10 vertices with one bridge can be obtained by combining complete graphs( which will give us 10 vertices) and adding a bridge between them. $K_9$ and $K_1$, $K_8$ and $K_2$ and so on till $K_5$ and $K_5$. Among listed $K_9$  and  $K_1$ have the largest number of vertices.

Comment: Why would a minimal connected subgraph of K_9 have 9 edges? The minimum connected subgraph of K_3 only has 3-1 edges

Answer (score 0):

Assume graph is simple.

Suppose $br$ is a bridge, then $G\setminus br$ is union of two conected subgraphs $A$ and $B$ with $a$ and $b$ nodes.

Since there is only one bridge $A$ and $B$ must have a Hamilton cycle if $a,b\geq 3$. So the number of edges $e$ in $G$ is at least $a+b+1=n+1$ and it is easy to see that number is achivable. If $a=1$ or $b=1$ then $e=n$. Clearly $a=2$ or $b=2$ is not possible else we would have 2 bridges.

On the other hand $$e\leq {a\choose 2}+{b\choose 2} +1 \leq {n-1\choose 2}+1$$

Comment: I don't think your lower bound is quite right. If $a=1$, then we don't need to add an extra edge for $A$, right?